# T-SQL - get only latest row for selected condition

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, query-optimization

I have table with measurement with column SERIAL_NBR, DATE_TIME, VALUE. 
There is a lot of data so when I need them to get the last 48 hours for 2000 devices

`Select * from MY_TABLE where [TIME]> = DATEADD (hh, -48, @TimeNow)`

takes a very long time.
Is there a way not to receive all the rows for each device, but only the latest entry? Would this speed up the query execution time?

Comment: Your question is not so clear. Is there indexes? If yes, please share them also. You placed here two really different desirable outputs (with question about query optimization), but for each of these outputs there might be different indexes and different approach how to reach your goal ... :) (and ofc , there is way how to get only latest entry, but with different query optimization aproach)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Assuming that there is column named deviceId(change as per your needs), you can use `top 1 with ties` with window function row_number:

```
Select top 1 with ties *
from MY_TABLE 
where [TIME]> = DATEADD (hh, -48, @TimeNow)
Order by row_number() over (
                    partition by deviceId
                    order by Time desc
                );
```

Comment: Strange this gets +2 as I honestly don't see how this might work. The example surely doesn't limit the output to the latest records.

Comment: @deroby - You should try the code before down voting the answer. This works exactly the same way as your answer and with much less code.

Comment: No it doesn't, I did try it. Copy paste the code, replace `MY_TABLE` with `sys.columns`, `TIME` with `column_id` and `deviceId` with `object_id` (and strip the `WHERE`). it will return me ALL records, not just the one with the latest column. 
// 
Rereading your answer and not just sticking to the example code you gave, you're right. This does work AFTER you apply your recommendation to your own example code !??! I didn't expect to get an IKEA example =P

Comment: @deroby - I confess I missed the `top 1 with ties` part in the SQL query (even though I mentioned it in the text before). Updated the answer. Thanks for bringing it to my attention. Here you go with your example of columns table - http://rextester.com/VURB69240 :)

Comment: Admittedly, I skimped the (short) text and simply copy pasted the code and then couldn't figure it out; rereading things from my part would have helped too =) Anyway up-voted again, I like it better than mine although again I wonder if it will outperform the `MAX()` approach.. as usually it probably depends.

Answer (score 2):

You can simply create *Common Table Expression* that sorts and groups the entries and then pick the latest one from there.

```
;WITH numbered
   AS ( SELECT [SERIAL_NBR], [TIME], [VALUE], row_nr = ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY [SERIAL_NBR] ORDER BY [TIME] DESC)
          FROM MY_TABLE 
         WHERE [TIME]> = DATEADD (hh, -48, @TimeNow) )
SELECT [SERIAL_NBR], [TIME], [VALUE]
  FROM numbered
 WHERE row_nr = 1 -- we want the latest record only
```

Depending on the amount of data and the indexes available this might or might not be faster than Anthony Hancock's answer.

Similar to his answer you might also try the following:
(from MSSQL's point of view, the below query and Anthony's query are pretty much identical and they'll probably end up with the same query plan)

```
SELECT [SERIAL_NBR] , [TIME], [VALUE]
  FROM MY_TABLE AS M
  JOIN (SELECT [SERIAL_NBR] , max_time = MAX([TIME])
          FROM MY_TABLE 
         GROUP BY [SERIAL_NBR]) AS L -- latest
    ON L.[SERIAL_NBR] = M.[SERIAL_NBR]
   AND L.max_time     = M.[TIME]
 WHERE M.DATE_TIME >= DATEADD(hh,-48,@TimeNow)
```

Answer (score 1):

Your listed column values and your code don't quite match up so you'll probably have to change this code a little, but it sounds like for each SERIAL_NBR you want the record with the highest DATE_TIME in the last 48 hours. This should achieve that result for you.

```
SELECT SERIAL_NBR,DATE_TIME,VALUE
FROM MY_TABLE AS M
WHERE M.DATE_TIME >= DATEADD(hh,-48,@TimeNow)
    AND M.DATE_TIME = (SELECT MAX(_M.DATE_TIME) FROM MY_TABLE AS _M WHERE M.SERIAL_NBR = _M.SERIAL_NBR)
```

Answer (score 0):

This will get you details of the latest record per serial number:

```
  Select t.SERIAL_NBR, q.FieldsYouWant
  from MY_TABLE t
  outer apply
  (
    selct top 1 t2.FieldsYouWant
    from MY_TABLE t2 
    where t2.SERIAL_NBR = t.SERIAL_NBR
    order by t2.[TIME] desc
  )q
  where t.[TIME]> = DATEADD (hh, -48, @TimeNow)
```

Also, worth sticking `DATEADD (hh, -48, @TimeNow)` into a variable rather than calculating inline.